# Implementing Birch for online clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I'm using Birch algorithm from sklearn on Python for online clustering. I have a sample data set that my CF-tree is built on. How do I go about incorporating new streaming data? For example, I'm using the following code:

```
brc = Birch(branching_factor=50,            
n_clusters=no,threshold=0.05,compute_labels=True)
brc.fit(sample_data)
```

Suppose I have a new data point x, how do I fit this new data point into the tree, and thus determine the cluster number?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation, use `partial_fit`